# How to use interface in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Im a amature programmer

I have a `DialogFragment` . `DialogFragment` have a `interface` :

```
public class FragmentEditClass extends DialogFragment
{
    //. . .


    public interface NotifyChanged
    {
        void updateRemoveClass(int position);
    }
}
```

I used interface in a Fragment Tab :

```
public class SecondTab extends Fragment implements FragmentEditClass.NotifyChanged
{
    //. . .

    @Override
    public void updateRemoveClass(int position) 
    {
       //. . .
    }
}
```

I show `DialogFragment` in  adapter :

```
FragmentEditClass.newInstance(classId , className , position)
    .show(secondTab.getFragmentManager() , "DialogFragmentClass");
```

I want to communicate between `fragmentTab` and `interface` in `DialogFragment` with the following way :

```
public class FragmentEditClass extends DialogFragment
{
    private NotifyChanged notifyChanged;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        notifyChanged = (NotifyChanged) getActivity();//This line
    }
}
```

Now problem is `getActivity()`. this method refer to SecondTab but SecondTab is in a MainActivity and i need refer to MainAcitvity.

**MyError :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user.classmanager.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.user.classmanager.FragmentEditClass$NotifyChanged
    at com.example.user.classmanager.FragmentEditClass.onCreate(FragmentEditClass.java:91)
```

Comment: getActivity() refers your parent Activity. Since your parent activity doesn't implements your interface the class cast exception is being thrown